# Spring Mvc Rest Webservice jstl form submittion HTTP Status 415 Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jstl, webservice-client

I am Using Spring Mvc Rest Webservice with JSTL form submittion.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form:form method="POST" action="rest/save" modelAttribute="employee">

<table>
<tr><td>
id &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<form:input type="text" path="id"/>
</td></tr>

<tr><td>
fname <form:input type="text" path="firstName"/>
</td></tr>

<tr><td>
lname <form:input type="text" path="lastName"/>
</td></tr>

<tr><td>
phone <form:input type="text" path="phone"/>
</td></tr>

</table>

<input type="submit" value="submit" >


</form:form>
```

Here is my controller function that accepts the request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = EmpRestURIConstants.SAVE_EMP,method =    RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String setemployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){


    dataServices.setemp(employee);
        return "success";   
}
```

This works fine and saves the employee when i use it with ajax submit or with using RESTClient

The Error returns is..
HTTP Status 415: The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported
```

How Can i set the Mime type with JSTL form submittion and how can i solve the problem.
Please Somebody help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're posting a form, the data are not sent as `JSON`, and since you have explicitly set that you're accepting only `consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` you get the `415` error. You can have all your cases covered by removing the `@RequestBody` and the `consumes` attribute, Spring MVC is smart enough to know what to do in all of your cases (form submition, RESTClient or ajax)

```
@RequestMapping(value = EmpRestURIConstants.SAVE_EMP,method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String setemployee(Employee employee){
    dataServices.setemp(employee);
        return "success";   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. that worked. I have seen before that the problem is caused by the @Resuestbody and consumes attribute. But I don't understood the reason why. Thanks a lot for the explanation.