# Why this Spring MVC controller method can't handle this POST Request (Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC application and I have the following problem.

Into a **FreeMarker** view (but is not so important that the view is made using FreeMarker) I have this form:

```
<form id="reg-form" name="reg-form" action="<@spring.url '/iscrizioneStep2' />" method="post">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cf">Codice fiscale:</label>
            <input type="text" id="cf" name="codiceFiscale" class="form-control input-mm" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo codice fiscale" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY, NOSPACE, L==16, CF]" data-validation-label="codice fiscale" aria-required="true" tabindex="10">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcOfhcTAAAAAE3D2hsa3UcyTQ0PI4upcZ759FDa" tabindex="20"></div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block submit-btn" aria-label="prosegui la registrazione" tabindex="30">Passaggio 2</button>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

As you can see the form is submittet to this action: **action="<@spring.url '/iscrizioneStep2' />"** performing a **POST** request.

This generate a POST request toward this URL (I see it using FireBug):

```
http://localhost:8080/iam-ssum-public/iscrizioneStep2?codiceFiscale=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&g-recaptcha-response=
```

So I think that it should send the input field having **name="codiceFiscale"** into the POST request.

Then I have this controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/iscrizioneStep2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String iscrizioneStep2(@RequestBody(required = true) IscrizioneStep1Form iscrizioneStep1Form, Model model)
        throws APIException {

    /*
     * Verifica se l'utenza è attivata per il codice fiscale
     */
    String codiceFiscale = iscrizioneStep1Form.getCodiceFiscale();

    ..............................................................
    ..............................................................
    ..............................................................

    return "myView";
}
```

So the data sended in the post request should be putted inside the **IscrizioneStep1Form iscrizioneStep1Form** parameter, that is:

```
public class IscrizioneStep1Form {

    /**
     * Codice fiscale
     */
    private String codiceFiscale;

    public String getCodiceFiscale() {
        return codiceFiscale;
    }

    public void setCodiceFiscale(String codiceFiscale) {
        this.codiceFiscale = codiceFiscale;
    }

}
```

But the problem is that this HTTP POST request is not handled by the **iscrizioneStep2()** method. When I submit the form don't enter into this method and into the Eclipse console I obtain the following error message:

```
11:55:43,949 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-6) Handler execution resulted in exception: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported
```

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `heders` param to your `RequestMapping` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/iscrizioneStep2", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `@RequestBody(required = true)` from your request method.
Here [Spring Mvc Rest Webservice jstl form submittion HTTP Status 415 Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790242/spring-mvc-rest-webservice-jstl-form-submittion-http-status-415-content-type-ap) has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in converter that knows how to convert content of the type `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `IscrizioneStep1Form`. Simply omit `@RequestBody`. Form data is automatically mapped to objects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when we use **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, Spring doesn't understand it as a RequestBody. So, if we want to use this
we must remove the **@RequestBody** annotation.

Then try the following:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/iscrizioneStep2", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String iscrizioneStep2(IscrizioneStep1Form iscrizioneStep1Form, Model model)        throws APIException {
                 //method body where
    }`

Note that removed the annotation **@RequestBody**

*answer*: [Http Post request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782025/http-post-request-with-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-not-workin/38252762#38252762)